# vba two columns combobox using external data

Tags: excel, combobox

I recently creating a workbook which contains a userform with a combobox, named "combobox1"
I have a code that brings data from other workbook in direction shown below whith range "B2:B...."
now i want to make it how to have a tow columns in a combobox the other column shuld bring data from same directory but the range for exp: "A1:A...."
i need your help 
thx.

```
    [Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

`Dim ListItems As Variant, i As Integer
`Dim SourceWB As Workbook
With Me.ComboBox1
.Clear ' remove existing entries from the listbox
' turn screen updating off,
' prevent the user from seeing the source workbook being opened
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' open the source workbook as ReadOnly
Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Mohsen\Desktop\new prj\Data base\partlist.xls", _
False, True)
ListItems = SourceWB.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B1468").Value
' get the values you want
SourceWB.Close False ' close the source workbook without saving changes
Set SourceWB = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ListItems = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ListItems)
' convert values to a vertical array
For i = 1 To UBound(ListItems)
.AddItem ListItems(i) ' populate the listbox
Next i
.ListIndex = -1 ' no items selected, set to 0 to select the first item


End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear about where the second column of data should come from so I have assumed that the first combobox column is from SourceWB, Sheet1, column B and that the second combobox column is from the same sheet in the column to the left of column B.  You can change these to suit.

I have also coded to identify the last datarow in column B.  This will prevent searching 1468 rows unnecessarily.  Again, please change if this is not helpful.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ListItems As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim listVal As Range
Dim srcLastRow As Long

'for testing purposes
Dim srcName As String
srcName = "C:\Users\Mohsen\Desktop\new prj\Data base\partlist.xls" 

    With Me.ComboBox1
        'Set the number of columns by code
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .Clear
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(srcName, False, True)
            'find the last row of data to prevent searching 1468 rows unnecessarily
            srcLastRow = SourceWB.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            For Each listVal In SourceWB.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B" & srcLastRow)
                .AddItem listVal.Value
                'Offset(0,-1) gets second column of data from cell to the left
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = listVal.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Next listVal
        SourceWB.Close False
        Set SourceWB = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        .ListIndex = -1
    End With
End Sub
```

Take a look at the Properties window for Combobox1, for other properties that you may require to set within the code.

Comment: thanks alot about your answer , so useful . i have linked the combobox value to range "C9" and it returns left column value to C9 and its OK, now i want to link the 2nd column (right one) to a cell for exp"B9", and i would like to have VBA code to set both of linking values.